# Mini fridge putty tape function

Tags: appliances

I have a mini fridge, and I noticed that it had two pieces of black putty tape on the refrigerant lines. What is the purpose of these?

They're much thicker than standard tape and the best way to describe them is as a putty with a strip of cellophane backing.

My best guess is that they're intended to seal some hole in the line or reinforce a weak weld or something, but that doesn't sound very safe since R600a is the flammable compound isobutane.

Comment: Change the frequency of vibration? Stop them rubbing...

Comment: Maybe, but they're just kinda hanging out on the pipes. They're not located at any rub points that I noticed. The vibration thing could be possible though, I suppose.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because not a Home Improvement related question

Comment: @Ack Well, I probably should have specified that the reason I'm asking is because knowing what they do could be critical to fixing my fridge. Plus, I can't seem to find this information anywhere.

Comment: A photo would be helpful, putty close to a penetration would be normal than anything I can think of, a repair we usually peal the neoprene insulation back add access valves / seal leaks then use the same insulation with the tape to insulate the lines.